# What are the specific hours of the day that remote Stack Overflow staff work?

Tags: discussion, company, stack-exchange-team

**How are the different time zones of remote team members at Stack Overflow accounted for?**

In a recent [interview](https://youtu.be/oQOkhz5cRqU?t=1446)  Joel Spolsky mentions that remote work is best done within similar time zones to allow high bandwidth communication through Google hangouts, slack etc.

In the interview Joel says "We pretty much hire people in Western Europe and North America" & "We overlap 4 or 5 hours a day"

Does this mean that Stack Overflow only hires on the East Coast of the USA?

If Stack Overflow does hire on the West Coast, how is the time zone difference of 10 hours accounted for between the  West Coast and Western Europe?

Comment: SE/SO has hired people based in the [Philippines](http://stackexchange.com/users/20808/tim-post) and [Japan](http://stackexchange.com/users/2184621/jmac). And [Colorado](http://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) isn't _that_ far from the West Coast.

Comment: Geoff Dalgas: Oregon, Jon Ericson: California, Jason Harvey: Alaska...

Comment: People on the west coast of the U.S. do overlap with people on the east coast by 4 or 5 hours a day. I don't think each person has to overlap with everyone else.

Comment: Are you asking for information that you can use in your own workplace, or so you know when to bug the SE staff most reliably? If it's the former, I don't really see how it's on topic; if the latter, it's unfair, and bordering on impolite. I don't see a good reason for this question; maybe you can [edit] to clarify what you're interested in here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Since when did questions have to be *justified*? This is  just asking for some basic information.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange has had employees scattered around the world.  Tim Post was in the Philippines for years, and jmac was in Japan.  I don't know if employees far from US/western-Europe time zones were expected to shift their hours for better collaboration, though I know that at least one did at least some of the time, based on interactions we had.

Fairly recently the SE job postings have started to specify time zones *where relevant*.  (Some pure-remote positions still get posted, and some positions are constrained to particular locales.)  Here's a sample from the [current listings](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here):

[image: job postings with time zones]

These listings say things like "time zone in (range)"; I don't know if that means "no one from east Asia need apply" or "your work day must match a time zone in this range".

Here's an unconstrained remote one, for comparison:

[image: remote posting]

Oh, and no, within the US it's not limited to the east coast.  I know people in Colorado, California, and Texas, and that's just on the community team.